# like operater does not work well in Access SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, sql-like

I am doing project management and have three tables to work with:
*Project*, *Task*, and *ProjectTypeLookup*.

The content of *ProjectTypeLookup* looks like:

```
Keyword ProjectType
*-TVC*  TVC
*-OTV*  OTV
*-KV*   KV
```

The content of *Task* is like:

```
projectid  projectname                  taskname
1          Sprite Summer 2016 -TVC(2nd) PRE-LINK TEST (1ST ROUND)
2          MM CNY 2017 -KV              SHOOTING
3          Sprite Revive 2017           STAGE 2 - CAMPAIGN IDEA
4          Sprite Summer 2016 -OTV      CHECK STORY BOARD WITH LEGAL, PAC & SRA
```

The SQL Code is like

```
SELECT 
t.projectname, 
t.taskname, 
p.p_status,
(SELECT pt.projecttype 
 FROM   projecttypelookup AS pt 
 WHERE  t.projectname LIKE pt.keyword) AS ProjectType
FROM   project AS p, 
       task AS t
WHERE  t.projectid = p.projectid
```

Basically I want the program automatically generate the *ProjectType* field (TVC or KV or OVT) based on the pre-set rules stored in *ProjectTypeLookup* table.

For example, if the project name is `Sprite Summer 2016 -TVC`, matching `*-TVC*`, the project type should be `TVC`.

Since not all the project names can match the rules, and unmatched names should have a empty value in *ProjectType* field, I used a subquery.

However it does not work well. I only see "TVC"s in the *ProjectType* field... no KV, no OTV.... Other project names all have empty ProjectType fields, like

```
projectname                   projecttype
Sprite Summer 2016 -TVC(2nd)  TVC
MM CNY 2017 -KV            
Sprite Revive 2017   
Sprite Summer 2016 -OTV
Coke Summer 2016 -TVC         TVC
```

Actually I can also do a LEFT JOIN but I do not know how to combine it with FROM WHERE structure....

Comment: Specifically, you have the correct number of commas, but in the wrong spots.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Bracuk. It's just copy paste error.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks! Comma problem fixed! It's just copy paste error. Since my original code is much longer, I cut a part of them.

Comment: Guys... I know... It's my stupidity... In table ProjectTypeLookup, every keyword has a space in the end except *-TVC*....